# Python Requests Login

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm creating a python script that will login to a torrent site and fetch the latest torrents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'takelogin.php',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.bitsoup.me/login.php', data=payload)
    request = c.get('https://www.bitsoup.me/browse.php?cat=19')
    print request.headers
    print request.text
```

When I try to the script above, I get

```
<tr><td align=center class=main style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">
<h1>Not logged in!</h1>
<p><b>Error:</b> The page you tried to view can only be used when you're logged in.</p>
<form method="post" action="takelogin.php">
<p>Note: You need cookies enabled to log in.</p>
<table border="0" cellpadding=5>
<tr><td class=rowhead>Username:</td><td align=left><input type="text" size=40 name="username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td class=rowhead>Password:</td><td align=left><input type="password" size=40 name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Log in!" class=btn></td></tr></table>
<input type="hidden" name="returnto" value="/browse.php?cat=19" />
</form>
```

Is my payload setup correct? It also says "you need cookies enabled to login", so would I have to setup cookie functionality in my script?

Comment: Sounds like your script is not posting the login cookie correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, only somebody with an account can actually help you, because it is impossible to debug this particular issue without an actual account. :(

Comment: @merlin2011 :( well it sucks  that the site disabled new registerations but can you clarify on the login cookie part?

Comment: You can try my answer first, and let me know whether that works. I just did some poking, and it appears that that message about cookies is displayed regardless of whether you have cookies enabled and disabled. Moreover, it looks like the library you are using *should* handle cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure speculation, because I cannot reproduce your issue without an account.

I think the issue is actually that you are issuing a `POST` to the wrong URL. You want to POST to the *target* of the form, not the *login* page. The reason is that you want to *emulate* what the login page is doing, which is `POST` to the `takelogin.php` site.

Try deleting the `action` from the payload, and replacing your `post` with the following.

```
c.post('https://www.bitsoup.me/takelogin.php', data=payload)
```

I deduce this because I only get the "Password Incorrect" HTML when I `POST` to `takelogin.php`, and nothing interesting with the OP's original POST.

Comment: @sevol, What do you know, I guess I was wrong. I *could* help without an account. :P

Comment: @sevol, Please consider accepting this answer if it addressed your issue.

Comment: I guess you were wrong but at the same time right! If your into torrents you should try this site once registration opens up again.

Comment: @sevol, Do me a favor and leave a comment if it opens. :P

Comment: If you want I can send you an invite. I just remembered that I have 4 left :) I will need your email.